# "Android OS" is continuously downloading something in the background, how can I stop that?

Tags: data-monitoring, background-data

My HTC One V (on 4.0 ICS) seems to be continuously downloading something even when it's inactive, and it's using the battery abnormally fast.

My data usage graph:
[image: data usage graph]
<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

On the first picture, the brown line is for the "Android OS" element, which as you can see is responsible for at least 60% of the data consumption. I don't know what Android is downloading, but it does it continuously and it has a big effect on my battery's life. When I disable mobile data, the battery usage line becomes flat (see second picture). How can I check what exactly "Android OS" is doing? And how can I disable this activity?

Here is the battery usage graph. As you can see, the line became flat when I've disabled mobile data.
[image: battery usage graph]
<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the culprit! I went to Settings > Call > Internet call settings and deleted the SIP account I had once created and forgot. The phone kept reaching the SIP server (probably to check for incoming calls).

I had to install a packet sniffer on the phone ([tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture&feature=search_result)) to see where the requests where going and realize I had configured a SIP account.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what apps you have installed, apps like facebook, twitter, google+ and others will download data in the background to keep current when you open the app.

With ICS, you can disable background data usage for specific apps:
[image: data usage]
<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

this is visible in the system settings -> data usage. you should then see a list of apps that are using data. it will also show the highest usage app. Clicking on the app brings you to a details screen that allows you to disable data usage or background usage.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but unfortunately this checkbox isn't available for the Android OS element.

Comment: interesting, i missed the part that it is actually Android OS. if you restart the device, does that continue to be the case?

Comment: @Cutter It's not available when you press the settings button while you're on that page?

Comment: @ott--I don't have a settings button, but holding the "recent apps" button (which is equivalent to pressing the settings button) has no effect (I don't have a menu popping up).

Comment: @ott-- Unless you meant the "View app settings" button, which is grayed out for me too!

Comment: @RyanConrad Yes. Do you have that checkbox for Android OS?

Comment: Look at http://www.1qaz.de/Screenshot_2012-08-23-00-16-23.png and http://www.1qaz.de/Screenshot_2012-08-23-00-16-34.png - this is from a Nexus S with 4.1.1

Comment: I don't have these menu items.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at something like [Onavo Count](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid) to monitor data usage?

Comment: I've just installed it. I hope it will give me the details about what Android OS is doing.

Comment: It turns out Onavo Count doesn't tell more than "Android OS + others"; that's the name of the app consuming most of the data.

Answer (score 0):

In Apps & notifications -> Advanced -> Special app access -> Unrestricted data, click on the overflow menu (3 dots stacked vertically) and select "Show system". Then turn off background data for all of them.