# "Android OS" uses a lot of data in background, how to turn off it?

Tags: settings

I have already read [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28100/android-os-is-continuously-downloading-something-in-the-background-how-can-I) and
[this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58620/android-os-uses-a-lot-of-data-in-background-how-to-turn-auto-system-update-chec) but can't stop the automatic blackground update.

I currently use Samsung grand 2 dual (SM-G7102) android 4.3 and **cellular** mode.

I'm setting-->usage “Restrict Background data” but the android OS is still running the updates in the background.(see picture)
help me please.

[image]

<sup>Click image(s) for larger version</sup>

I'm setting “Restrict Background data” in 24/08/2557 but On 25/08/2557, "Android OS" was still sending out to cellular.

[image]

<sup>Click image(s) for larger version</sup>

I'm allow Facebook, Line and Messager can use cellular but don't want the "Android OS" Update. The mobile is rooted

The "android os" was “Restrict Background data”.
Help me please.

Comment: your 2nd screen shot is not clear from what you want. Could you please update your screen shot without the notification bar sliding down and add another screen shot for the options that are enabled in the shortcut bar.

Comment: Put Auto-Sync in Settings to *off*.

Comment: update picture and detail.

Comment: This appears to be a similar question to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58620/android-os-uses-a-lot-of-data-in-background-how-to-turn-auto-system-update-chec Thanks for the hints from other answers. This is an indirect answer but while on mobile Internet I used Mobiwol firewall without rooting to block "Android OS" background data. It appears to work on Galaxy S5.

Comment: @ohno Did you try under the Update>select update only via WiFi,Play Store>Update apps only via WiFi as checked

Comment: I tried everything! The ONLY resolution is to remove your google account from the phone when not in use. 
 level processes into their own applications (such as photos, mail, etc) so there is no way to block data use. The only option is to remove the google account when not in use and re-add it when 
you need to update apps via google play. As a side benifit google will also no longer track you when you use gmail or their apps in the browser. YAY!

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Google Backup.Switch Google Backup off and your problem will be solved. Follow these steps:

1. Open Photos app.
2. From options goto Settings.
3. Touch Auto Backup and switch the toggle On or Off.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a "Root Firewall" in your mobile by which you can control the Internet connectivity of all apps (including system apps). They also offer to block only Data connection and not wifi connection for a specific app.

The app I'm using is "[AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall)" (free).

Note: This type of apps only works on Rooted android phones.
[Here](http://lifehacker.com/5789397/the-always-up-to-date-guide-to-rooting-any-android-phone) is the greate article about rooting in android. It is highly recommended for you to know everything about rooting before choosing this option.

If you have decided to go along with AFWall+ and you understand the risk of rooting your mobile device then visit [this](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/FAQ) link to configure your AFwall+ for the first time use.

Further check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/switch-to-default-keyboard-in-password-fields/116484#116484) answer by @firelord for step by step configuration and screenshots of AFWall+.

If you need further help and have a question related to this answer please comment. I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: @Firelord thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my answer.

Comment: +1 for the official FAQ among other things. In case somebody need screenshots, try my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/116484/96277).

Answer (score 0):

All other things are also helpful like disabling **Auto Sync
Background data**, etc.
Try doing this:

- Go to **Settings -> Apps -> All Apps**.
- Go to the last app **Update Centre**  and then tap on it.
- After opening it tap on **Force close**.

I think is is the probable cause of the background data usage by Android OS. And by doing this you may get rid of it.

**Note**: You need to remember that you will have to do this trick every time you restart the device. If you have a pending System Update, then its icon from the notification tray will disappear. This directly means that your device will no longer search for System Updates until you restart it.

In short, to stop OS using mobile data, force stop Update app.

Comment: Its not `u` but `you`. Please refrain from using the former.

Answer (score -1):

If you agree then try to use developer options. By using this option when you leave or minimize your app with home button or anything other, your app activity automatically stop. It shows only activity view on task manager but displays activity as not working.

Go to settings -> find Developer option. Tap seven time on developer option and new Developer window will open. Now find "Do not keep activity". If it is not marked, then mark it. By default it will be not marked. Now try to open any app activity and minimize. Then try to restart activity from recent task and see magic. It will not start. It means it stoped.When you want to disable this from working then simple switch off your developer option.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Settings → Data usage → click on the 3 vertical boxes in right top corner → tick the Restrict background data → then remove the tick in Auto sync data.